Why doesn't `PAULI_CHANNEL_1` require approximation in Stim sometimes?
There are circuits in which PAULI_CHANNEL_1 doesn't require approximation given certain probabilities (seems like probabilities below 0.24 for some reason), but then the same circuit with higher probabilities does require approximating:
y_prob = 0.23
c = stim.Circuit(f"""
H 0
PAULI_CHANNEL_1(0.4, {y_prob}, 0.23) 0 1 2 3
H 0
M 0 1 2
DETECTOR rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-3]
DETECTOR rec[-2]
DETECTOR rec[-3]
""")
c.detector_error_model(approximate_disjoint_errors=False)

stim.DetectorErrorModel('''
    error(0.63) D0
    error(0.63) D0 D1
    error(0.46) D0 D2
''')

but then the same circuit just with an increased probability raises an error because approximations are not allowed:
y_prob = 0.24
c = stim.Circuit(f"""
H 0
PAULI_CHANNEL_1(0.4, {y_prob}, 0.23) 0 1 2 3
H 0
M 0 1 2
DETECTOR rec[-1] rec[-2] rec[-3]
DETECTOR rec[-2]
DETECTOR rec[-3]
""")
c.detector_error_model(approximate_disjoint_errors=False)

ValueError: Encountered the operation PAULI_CHANNEL_1 during error analysis, but this operation requires the `approximate_disjoint_errors` option to be enabled.


Behind the scenes, stim tries to find an accurate conversion by either noticing it's a simple case or by using a few iterations of Newton's method. If it manages to find an accurate conversion, it doesn't bother raising an error.
Presumably your problem is right on the boundary of where the method converges, or possibly of where an exact solution even exists.
bool stim::try_disjoint_to_independent_xyz_errors_approx(
    double x, double y, double z, double *out_x, double *out_y, double *out_z, size_t max_steps) {
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0 || x + y + z > 1) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0 || x + y + z > 1");
    }

    // Re-arrange the problem so identity is the most likely case.
    double i = std::max(0.0, 1.0 - x - y - z);
    if (i < x) {
        auto result = try_disjoint_to_independent_xyz_errors_approx(i, z, y, out_x, out_y, out_z, max_steps);
        *out_x = 1 - *out_x;
        return result;
    }
    if (i < y) {
        auto result = try_disjoint_to_independent_xyz_errors_approx(z, i, x, out_x, out_y, out_z, max_steps);
        *out_y = 1 - *out_y;
        return result;
    }
    if (i < z) {
        auto result = try_disjoint_to_independent_xyz_errors_approx(y, x, i, out_x, out_y, out_z, max_steps);
        *out_z = 1 - *out_z;
        return result;
    }

    // Solve analytically if an exact solution exists.
    if (x + z < 0.5 && x + y < 0.5 && y + z < 0.5) {
        double s_xz = sqrt(1 - 2 * x - 2 * z);
        double s_xy = sqrt(1 - 2 * x - 2 * y);
        double s_yz = sqrt(1 - 2 * y - 2 * z);
        double a = 0.5 - 0.5 * s_xz * s_xy / s_yz;
        double b = 0.5 - 0.5 * s_xy * s_yz / s_xz;
        double c = 0.5 - 0.5 * s_xz * s_yz / s_xy;
        if (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0) {
            *out_x = a;
            *out_y = b;
            *out_z = c;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // If no exact solution exists, resort to approximations.
    double a = x;
    double b = y;
    double c = z;
    for (size_t step = 0; step < max_steps; step++) {
        // Compute current error.
        double ab = a * b;
        double ac = a * c;
        double bc = b * c;
        double a_i = 1.0 - a;
        double b_i = 1.0 - b;
        double c_i = 1.0 - c;
        double ab_i = a_i * b_i;
        double ac_i = a_i * c_i;
        double bc_i = b_i * c_i;
        double x2 = a * bc_i + a_i * bc;
        double y2 = b * ac_i + b_i * ac;
        double z2 = c * ab_i + c_i * ab;
        double dx = x2 - x;
        double dy = y2 - y;
        double dz = z2 - z;
        double err = fabs(dx) + fabs(dy) + fabs(dz);
        if (err < 1e-14) {
            // Good enough.
            *out_x = a;
            *out_y = b;
            *out_z = c;
            return true;
        }

        // Make a Newton-Raphson step towards the solution.
        double da = bc_i - bc;
        double db = ac_i - ac;
        double dc = ab_i - ac;
        a -= dx / da;
        b -= dy / db;
        c -= dz / dc;
        a = std::max(a, 0.0);
        b = std::max(b, 0.0);
        c = std::max(c, 0.0);
    }
    *out_x = a;
    *out_y = b;
    *out_z = c;
    return false;
}

